# PYQT5 with Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

[image]I'm trying to build a Python GUI app that adds information to a list with pyqt5 but I'm getting errors.the application should be able to display items that are entered into the lineedit inside the listwidget.

Below is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
form2 = uic.loadUi("login2.ui")

def add_item():
    if not form2.LineEdit_item.text() == "":
        form2.ListWidget.addItem(form2.LineEdit_item.text())
        form2.LineEdit_item.setText("")

form2.PushButton_addItem.clicked.connect(add_item)
form2.show()
app.exec()
```

and below is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Windows 10/PycharmProjects/mygui2.py", line 11, in <module>
    form2.PushButton_addItem.clicked.connect(add_item)
AttributeError: 'QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'PushButton_addItem'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do i get this sorted out.

Comment: Is `PushButton_addItem` defined in your ui file ?

Comment: Push_Button is actually a button and addItem is a normal code with using List Widget which doesn't need to be defined and it wasn't defined on the video tutorials i was watching.

Comment: Please post your .ui file. It's easier to see what's wrong that way.

Comment: i just did that

Comment: okay thanks i really want to learn more including the database gui applications and more complex programs.i'll add you up now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything should work if you specify the name correctly
for the `objectName` of the`QPushButton` widget.

[image]

---

[image]
**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

form2 = uic.loadUi("login2.ui")

def add_item():
    if not form2.LineEdit_item.text() == "":
        form2.ListWidget.addItem(form2.LineEdit_item.text())
        form2.LineEdit_item.setText("")

form2.PushButton_addItem.clicked.connect(add_item)
form2.show()
app.exec()
```

---

**login2.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>330</width>
    <height>258</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QListWidget" name="ListWidget"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="LineEdit_item"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="PushButton_addItem">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>330</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]